# Extreme difficulty getting UWP MS-Test to work in a stable manner

Tags: uwp, mstest

I have a Windows 10 UWP app that I would like to develop, however after I create a new project targeting Build 15063 till 17125.

1. I create the Class Library (Universal Windows) as well as the Unit
   Test App
2. I then set the capabilities I need in the test app
3. Then I update the nuget packages, I get my first hint that my day
   will be a …. as the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk fails to update. the error i get is:

> Error Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported
>   file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets".

Does any one have a fix on this issue?

[image: nuget packages]

Comment: Have you checked dependencies & requirement of nuget package, it may req vs2017 15.6 or other dependency also try to empty obj and bin folder in your project folder

Comment: Unfortunately this does not sole the issue, as mentioned clean build, even whiped the computer and re-installed the VS from scratch. there seems to be a compatibility issue

Comment: Have you checked by changing min sdk and vs updated to 15.6 or higher than 15.0

Comment: Yes, I have tried all intermediate releases

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To all that have the same issue... 
I have downloaded and installed the preview version of VS 2017 (version 4.7.0.2556) and now my errors have gone away, I have been able to update my nuget packages this: 
[image: Nuget versions]
aand I am targeting following windows releases:
[image]

Happy coding :-)